# How to build google maps like morethanamap ?

Tags: google-maps, responsive-design

I want to build google maps like http://www.morethanamap.com/demos/places

What skills I must learn to build it?
or Where are documents how to learn it?

sorry for my English.
Thank you.

Comment: You might also be interestred in the following live stream next Monday: https://plus.google.com/events/c705js7ns4np47jat9qfidv6sqc - In it, Google Engineers will talk about how morethanamap.com has been built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 documentation.

See it here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Once you start working with all the code and examples given in this site, you can very well start building interactive maps like the one in your link.